# tables are not reflecting in redshift when i am creating in SQL workbench

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-redshift, workbench

I am using following script.

```
create table public.james(
  player varchar(256),
  ID int);
```

Comment: 1- check if the statement is successful, 2- check if both DB servers are the same.

Comment: yes the statement is successful and i have cross verified the DB server as well

Comment: 3 - make sure you are looking at the right schema , 4- make sure the user you logged in with in your workbench has sufficient  permission

Comment: How are you checking for the existence of this new table?  Some methods only work if there is data in the table but other will show empty tables.  Did you remember to COMMIT?  Depending on your connection settings you will need to commit your actions before others can see it.

Comment: i am trying to create table through workbench and then it should reflect the same in the redshift console right ?  but its saying table created in workbench but not reflecting in the redshift console